# PHP Cross Domain Redirection Session Lost

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, facebook, cross-domain

Recently I'm working on a site that has a facebook authentication in it, basically it redirects to the facebook page (a header redirect) and the user authenticates it and then facebook redirects back to the site. Everything is fine on my local server but when I upload to the actual server things screw up. When facebook redirects back to the site the session information (some login details) is lost.
I searched and seemed to me that this is a common problem, yet I tried all the proposed solutions (like adding **session_write_close()** or **exit()** after the header, passing the session_id) none of them works. I'm using Zend so the "forgetting session_start" is not the issue.
Some say it has something to deal with the https difference, some say it's a cross-domain thing and it's not fixable, I'm kind of lost right now, anyone who has suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I solved it by setting up SSL for the site. It is because of the http & https problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this heading in your init()

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('P3P', 'CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
```

It's a common problem with IE and this will fix it in some cases.